# c# Pattern Matching Properties of a Generic Class?

Tags: c#, generics, properties, switch-statement

I have a `Dictionary<string,string> dictionary` where the key holds the name of a property, and the value the corresponding value. I then have a number of different models and a Generic class that handles those different models. I am trying to set the values of the relevant properties through pattern matching (unless there is a better way?).

```
var record = new T();

foreach (var property in ReflectiveOps.Properties(record))
{
    if (dictionary.ContainsKey(property.Name))
    {
         switch ...???
```

I've tried switching over `property.PropertyType` and then `case int` and `case int i` but that didn't work. I could do an `if(property.PropertyType.Name == "int"{...}` - that works. Can this be done with a switch?

Comment: `property.PropertyType == typeof(int)` would be better

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Yes, but that, too, seems to only work in the `if..then` statement. If I put it into the case, I get an error that a constant value is expected.

Comment: @PatrickHofman but a great suggestion... (bug catching atm, and saw that the name "int32" happens to be different to "int" but with your `typeof` the same :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach to deal with properties typed at run-time is to construct a dictionary of actions based on property type. In other words, instead of writing

```
// This does not work, but imagine for a moment that it does:
switch (property.PropertyType) {
    case typeof(int): DoSomethingWithInt(property, val, obj); break;
    case typeof(string): DoSomethingWithString(property, val, obj); break;
    case typeof(long): DoSomethingWithLong(property, val, obj); break;
    default: throw new InvalidOperationException($"Unsupported type: {property.PropertyType.Name}");
}
```

write this:

```
var opByType = new Dictionary<Type,Action<PropertyInfo,string,object>> {
    { typeof(int), (p, s, o) => DoSomethingWithInt(property, val, obj) }
,   { typeof(string), (p, s, o) => DoSomethingWithString(property, val, obj) }
,   { typeof(long), (p, s, o) => DoSomethingWithLong(property, val, obj) }
};
```

Actions in the `opByType` dictionary correspond to the code inside the corresponding case of the `switch` that does not compile.

Now you can use `property.PropertyType` to retrieve the action for the type, and invoke that action.